# Помогите разобраться с селекторами css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Как например задать класс второму по счету div, или задать только первому нужные стили, если у каждого однаковые названия классов? Немного не понятно с уровнями, как правильно задавать по уровню, что бы не плодить css классы?

```html
<div class="selector">
  <div class="classname"></div>
  <div class="classname"></div>
  <div class="classname"></div>
  <div class="classname"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления стиля к элементам на основе нумерации в дереве элементов используется псевдокласс `:nth-child`:

```
.class:nth-child(odd | even | <число> | <выражение>) {...
    // Styles
}
```

#### Значения

**odd** - Все нечетные номера элементов.

**even** - Все четные номера элементов.

**число** - Порядковый номер дочернего элемента относительно своего родителя. Нумерация начинается с 1, это будет первый элемент в списке.

**выражение** - Задается в виде **an+b**, где **a** и **b** целые числа, а **n** — счетчик, который автоматически принимает значение 0, 1, 2...

#### Примеры

В вашем случае для стилизации второго элемента используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child(2)`:

```css
.child{
   background:green;
   width:150px;
   height:100px;
}

.child:nth-child(2){
   background:#ccc;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

А для стилизации первого элемента используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child(1)` или же `:first-child`:

```css
.child{
   background:green;
   width:150px;
   height:100px;
}

.child:first-child{
   background:#ccc;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Псевдокласс :nth-child Вам в помощь уважаемые ;)
Дальше уже дело креатива)
https://webref.ru/css/nth-child

```css
.selector div {
  background-color:black;
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom:2.5px;
}

.selector div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:red;
}
.selector div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:green;
}
.selector div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:blue;
}
.selector div:nth-child(4) {
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: попахивает индуским кодом ))

Comment: Как пример основу брал для списков <ul><li></li>...</ul> где очень редко прописывают классы для li-элементов. может быть это то что автор и искал ;) согласен пример не из легких)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.child{
background:red;
width:150px;
height:100px;
}

.child:nth-child(2){
background:#ccc;
width:100px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```